# how to set the default in dropdown?

Tags: jsp, jsf

I have dropdown with dynamic values.for example in dropdown have 1,5,10,20.

when page loading need to display the 5 only.How to do in the jsf ?

Comment: provide the code of the view and the bean

Answer (score 1):

Preset the property associated with the `value` attribute with the desired value in bean's constructor.

```
public Bean() {
    this.selectedItem = 5;
}
```